# How To Modify Data in A cell in Excel

Tags: qt

This is My Code and i am unable to set value/Modify value in a cell using 
  "QAxObject"...is there anyone help to get out from this issue

```
enter code here
QAxObject * range1 = range->querySubObject("Cells(int,int)",2,2);
range1->setPropertyWritable("Value",true);
range1->setProperty("Value","Serial");
qDebug()<<"propertyWritable === "
        << range1->property("Value");
```